# array_map with access to keys

Tags: php, arrays

I need to iterate over an array that looks like this:

```
$myArray = array(
  'key1' => array('subkey' => 'subvalue'),
  'key2' => array('subkey' => 'subvalue'),
)
```

Into each nested associative array, I want to add a key-value pair based on the outside key, like this:

```
$myNewArray = array(
  'key1' => array('subkey' => 'subvalue', 'newkey' => 'only for key1'),
  'key2' => array('subkey' => 'subvalue'),
)
```

Ideally, I'm looking for something like:

```
$myNewArray = array_map(function($key, $value) {
    if ($key == 'key1') {
        $value['newkey'] = 'only for key1';
    }
    return $value;
}, $myArray);
```

However, that obviously doesn't work as `callback` isn't given two parameters but only one. I could do something like this:

```
$myNewArray = array_map(function($key, $value) {
    if ($key == 'key1') {
        $value['newkey'] = 'only for key1';
    }
    return WHAT??
}, array_keys($myArray), $myArray);
```

However, what do I return here? It seems to always construct a new array, i.e. discarding my string keys (`key1` and `key2`), while a single-array `array_map()` keeps them.

I can use `array_walk()` but it has a rather strange API (flipped parameter order, array passed by reference etc.) so I would generally prefer if this could be achieved using `array_map()`. Can it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm afraid [`array_walk()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) IS the way to do this.

If you don't like `array_walk()` and insist on doing it with [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php), well, it's possible. It involves using also `array_keys()`, `array_values()` and `array_combine()`, it is long and ugly but doable:

```
$myNewArray = array_combine(
    array_keys($myArray),
    array_map(
        function($key, $value) {
            if ($key == 'key1') {
                $value['newkey'] = 'only for key1';
            }
            return $value;
        },
        array_keys($myArray),
        array_values($myArray)     // can omit array_values() and use $myArray
    )
);
```

You can also do it using [`array_reduce()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) but it's the same mess:

```
$myNewArray = array_reduce(
    array_keys($myArray),
    function (array $carry, $key) use ($myArray) {
        $value = $myArray[$key];
        if ($key == 'key1') {
            $value['newkey'] = 'only for key1';
        }
        $carry[$key] = $value;
        return $carry;
    },
    array()
);
```

I hope you have a condition more complex than `$key == 'key1'` because only for this it is not worth it writing complex traversal. Isn't it easier to just access the right element and modify it?

```
$myArray['key1']['newkey'] = 'only for key1';
```

Comment: Yes, the transformation is far more complex, I just gave the minimal example that shows the challenge. Thanks for your answer, the first method actually doesn't look too ugly to me, though the array_walk() method will certainly be shorter. I just don't like passing arrays by reference at all.

Answer (score 1):

`array_map` only passes the value not the key.  `array_walk` is very similar to the `array_map`.  Just define the value as a reference.  It takes the key where `array_map` does not.  ALso, this modifies `$myArray`:

```
array_walk($myArray, function(&$value, $key) {
    if ($key == 'key1') {
        $value['newkey'] = 'only for key1';
    }
});
```

From the PHP manual, there does seem to be an `array_map` method using `array_keys` as another array:

```
$myNewArray = array_combine(array_keys($myArray), array_map(function($key, $value) {
    if ($key == 'key1') {
        $value['newkey'] = 'only for key1';
    }
    return  $value;
}, array_keys($myArray), $myArray));
```

Comment: Yes, this works, however, as your example shows, the API is confusing and it's easy to make a mistake - $myNewArray in your example will be true :) But I get it, thanks.

Comment: I just spotted that when I was working with `array_map`.  Edited.

Comment: Your second example will return an array of associative arrays, which is different from just associative array.

Comment: Fixed, just got longer and longer...  Whether it's confusing or not, `array_walk` is the proper and standard way.